# Two boolean variables in Java

Tags: java, variables, boolean

I would like to program in java two Boolean variables which are corelated in a way that one is allways false and one allways true. So if you set one to true the other one would automaticly change to false.

Comment: Sounds like you need one `Boolean` and a logic negation...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use variables - use methods.

Before using variables

```
class Before {
    boolean first;
    boolean second;

    boolean setFirst(boolean newValue) {
        first = newValue;
        second = !first;
    } 

    boolean setSecond(boolean newValue) {
        second = newValue;
        first = !second;
    }
}
```

make this better like so: use a single piece of data (which is what you really have) and use methods for the logic.

```
class After {
    private boolean value;

    boolean first() {
        return value;
    }

    boolean second() {
        return !value;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 because your `After` is essentially what I was going to answer with.

Comment: +1 Agreed.  This also solves potential problems with update anomalies.  Although depending on context, he doesn't necessarily need the second method either - for example, exterior code should probably be more concerned with `isAlive()` and `!isAlive()`, rather than having a second method `isDead()` (There's nothing wrong with your answer, just pointing out for conceptual cleanliness).

Comment: @X-Zero I completely agree. However, I could see how an `isDead()` method would be beneficial if it's used a lot just for cleanliness purposes. Besides, you may have reason to have something simultaneously both not dead and not alive (like a zombie state?) in the future. By putting the logic of "dead means not alive" in one location, you consolidate the change for later. So yes I completely agree it depends entirely on the context.

Answer (score 3):

Use setters and getters to manage the logic for you.

```
class Foo{

    private boolean _bool1;
    private boolean _bool2;

    public void setBool1(boolean value)
    {
       _bool1 = value;
       _bool2 = !value;
    }

    public void setBool2(boolean value)
    {
       _bool2 = value;
       _bool1 = !value;
    }

    public boolean getBool1() { return _bool1 ;}

    public boolean getBool2() { return _bool2 ;}
}
```

Comment: can I -1 for hungarian notation on the member variables? :-{

Comment: @glowcoder hungarian notation would be like bBool1 and bBool2. _memberName is kinda the standard for c# class fields. I'm not very sure about java.

Comment: It seems to be it's simply a replacement for the `m` in `mbBool1`. But that's just me... I didn't really DV for it :)

Answer (score 2):

use smart setters

```
class Blah {
   private bool1 = true;
   private bool2 = false;


   setBool1(val) {
      this.bool1 = val;
      this.bool2 = !val;
   }

   setBool2(val) {
       this.bool2 = val;
       this.bool1 = !val;
   }

   // more setters/getters

}
```

note I'm not sure if you really need this.  If the 2 booleans are always opposites, why not just have 1 bool and make decisions based on it, instead of making decisions based on 2 bools?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want `boolean` rather than `Boolean`

I also suspect you only need one field, flag1 with a method

```
 public boolean getFlag2() {
      return !flag1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Opposites {
  protected boolean x = true;
  protected boolean y = false;
  public boolean getX() { return x; }
  public boolean getY() { return y; }
  public boolean toggle() { x=!x; y=!y; }
}

Opposites o = new Opposites();
o.getX(); // => true
o.getY(); // => false
o.toggle();
o.getX(); // => false
o.getY(); // => true
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use only one boolean variable:

```
boolean flag = true;
/*
flag is true
!flag is false
*/

...

flag = false;
/*
flag is false
!flag is true
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the opposite with `!myVar` instead of having two variables. This can be in a function if you want.